# Assigning a Hebrew message to NSString sometimes shows html tags like quot&

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring, uilabel

I am working on a project which is bilingual (English and Hebrew).
While assigning Hebrew name to uilabel it is unable to display name with double quotes (") in it and instead shows quot& written with Hebrew text.

```
(lldb) po str
 פיקסיטאפ בע"
```

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97CND.png)

Comment: Show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace text with

```
 str = [[[[[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&" ]
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;"  withString:@"\""]
   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#39;"  withString:@"'" ]
  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;"  withString:@">"]
 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString: @"<" ];
```

Comment: in case of right to left language when i get name from service end it contains quot& not &quot

Comment: Show your text with quot& and i already work with many hebrew apps and this code works well

Comment: I can't understand why people did this for right answer. if you think this answer is not right you can put your answer and also comment on my answer where i did wrong.